# Why does my circular saw cut to the right of the notch?

Tags: circular-saw

I don't know if I'm having a brain fart and this saw has always done this, or my more recent cuts required being more accurate, but my Craftsman circular saw cuts about an 1/8" to the right of the notch cutout. Is this normal, I thought it was aligned with the center to right side within the notch?

I replaced the blade and took it back off again to make sure it is 100% aligned, in it's notch (the blade hole), sitting flush and tightened completely.

I don't see any lateral movement on the saw that would adjust that notch to the blade. I also looked for bent or damage but don't see any either. I know the left side of the notch says 45 degrees and I get that for when the saw is tilted at a 45 but this is flat. I put that blue painters tape to basically put where the alignment is (still needing to account for saw blade width of cut).

Is this normal or is something amiss with this saw setup?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here are pictures of the arbor to show I still can't see why the blade would be bumped out.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Was your saw ever dropped?  That could have bent the shoe enough to explain what you're seeing.  (Full disclosure...I dropped mine and had to bend it back.)

Comment: Normal that you're using the notch and it went wrong? Yes. Look at where the blade is at all times; that's what's happening. Notch gets you to within an eighth inch either way, then you kiss it with the blade. The rest is your job.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you don't have a knockout or adapter from the previous blade stuck to the motor shaft or to the inboard side of the blade. That would move the kerf one blade thickness to the right.

I don't mean to state the obvious, but I've been known to look right at something and not see it. It's worth your time to take the blade off again just to have a look.

Comment: From the picture the blade is not in the middle of the blade guard, but is shifted to the outside. In my decades old Craftsman it is right in the middle.